# How to auto wire spring data repository in another spring based project (without spring data context)

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two spring based projects, project-a with spring data and project-b simple spring based application with out spring data, project a is referenced in project b. In project b application context, i couldn't able to scan the spring data repositories present in project a using the annotation `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.projecta"></jpa:repositories>` it throws me below error.

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
[junit] Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connect identifier was empty.
```

Let me know if you have ever come across this.